# How to run GNU screen in detached mode over serial console and save output?

Tags: logs, gnu-screen, serial-port, serial-console

I want to use GNU screen to run a single command in detached mode over serial console and save it's output to the log file on the host where screen is running. Basically, non-interactive equivalent of the following actions:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 # connect to serial console "/dev/ttyUSB0" using speed "115200"
ctrl+a H # start logging
some command
ctrl+a k y # quit
```

I know how to run a single command in detached mode in the current shell:

```
screen -d -m -L some command
# output is saved to screenlog.0
```

But I don't understand how to do the same thing while also attaching to a serial console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test this properly on a serial port, but I think this might work:

```
$ screen -S serial -L -d -m /dev/ttyUSB0
$ screen -S serial -X stuff 'some command\n'
```

My version of `screen` accepts an argument to `-L`, the name of the log file. Apparently not all versions do. Another way to set the log file name would be with `screen -S serial -X logfile filename` (if that works). `screen` buffers the output to the log for a while before writing. By default the timeout is 10 seconds, but [see `logfile flush NN` to change that](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Logging).

`-X` sends a command to a running `screen`, and `stuff`, well, ["stuffs" the given string as input in the current window](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Paste.html#index-stuff-165).

Comment: @ilkkachu It doesn't work. `screen` seem to interpret everything after "-L" as a command to run: `Cannot exec 'logfile': No such file or directory`. If I replace "logfile" with "echo", log file "screenlog.0" is created with output "-d -m /dev/ttyUSB0".

Comment: @Thunderbeef, mhmh, it seems to work for me, with `Screen version 4.05.00 (GNU) 10-Dec-16` on Debian. But I suppose you could just leave the log file name out and use the default, or use `screen -X logfile ...` to set the file name.

Comment: @ilkkachu My version is `4.03.01`. Without "logfile" it works properly (log saved to default file "screenlog.0"). Thanks! For the reference, you could also add that you need to quit session afterwards: `screen -S serial -X quit` (for me, the log is not updated until I quit session).

Comment: @ilkkachu Also, my `man screen` doesn't show that `-L` accepts an argument: `-L   tells screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows.`. If you'll update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Thunderbeef, It's not listed in the [HTML manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen)  either (then again, that says "last updated February 21, 2009"...). But the man page on my Debian system does list it, so I'll just assume it's some unofficial addition. Dunno.

Comment: @Thunderbeef, edited.